# 2 arrays UPDATE mysql query. 1 array contains values to update other array contains the unique ID to be updated

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I have the following two arrays:

```
$array1 = (-5, -1, 9, 0, 5);
$array2 = (22, 19, 13, 11, 4);
```

NOTE: There is lots of code in between, which means the final output of the arrays are comma separated, as would be expected in an SQL query. E.G:

```
echo $array1;
```

output:

```
-5, -1, 9, 0, 5
```

I want to do something along the lines of this:

```
$UpdSQL ="UPDATE tbl_test SET ing_ml=('$array1') WHERE ing_id IN ('$array2')";
```

The order of both arrays match.  So what I would like to happen is the following:

```
ID  | ing_ml
22  | -5
19  | -1
13  | 9
etc | etc
```

However, I just can not figure out how to do it.  Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Create a prepared UPDATE statement and execute it in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
$array1 = [-5, -1, 9, 0, 5];
$array2 = [22, 19, 13, 11, 4];

$combined = array_combine($array2, $array1);

print_r($combined);

/* outputs:
Array
(
    [22] => -5
    [19] => -1
    [13] => 9
    [11] => 0
    [4] => 5
)
*/

foreach ($combined as $key => $value) {
  echo "UPDATE tbl_test SET ing_ml = '$value' WHERE ing_id = '$key';";
}

/* outputs:
UPDATE tbl_test SET ing_ml = '-5' WHERE ing_id = '22';
UPDATE tbl_test SET ing_ml = '-1' WHERE ing_id = '19';
UPDATE tbl_test SET ing_ml = '9' WHERE ing_id = '13';
UPDATE tbl_test SET ing_ml = '0' WHERE ing_id = '11';
UPDATE tbl_test SET ing_ml = '5' WHERE ing_id = '4';
*/
```

Comment: `array_combine()` is a good suggestion, But you should use a prepared  statement and define it outside the loop. For the sake of security and performance.

Comment: It was a demonstration for how the OP could use array_combine.

Comment: That's fine.. But you can improve your answer.

Comment: This does exactly what I am after. However, when I try to execute it, only the first record is updated, the rest error with:  `Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE tbl_test SET ing_ml='-1' WHERE ing_id='19'' at line 1`